# How to find the position of a specific row in a laravel collection(already fetched)

Tags: mysql, laravel, position

I need the position of a particular row from an already fetched the collection of models in laravel

`$data=Lessions::where('status',1)->where('teacher_id',56)->get();`
how to find the position of
`$data->where('student_id',3)`
We can do it by foreach loop.
anyone can suggest the more optimized way, without using foreach loop.
Note: i want position(from top to bottom) not id.

Comment: You are going to do a `foreach` loop 100, there is no way to get some data (that you do not know the position) without looping...

Comment: @matiaslauriti i am asking about something built in ! How can you say no data without looping. User::get() where is loop ? User::where('status',1)->count() where is loop ?

Comment: @mati and it is possible in raw sql for your kind information !

Comment: Your title says "_already fetched_"...

Comment: @matiaslauriti question have a valid answer. You can say it's impossible to get position without loop. simply. Negating question doesn't make sense. Question is valid you don't know answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this from many ways. First which i remember use Laravel Helper.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
$filtered = Arr::where($array, function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->student_id == 3 ? $value: '';
});
```

Also you can use map helper as well.

```
$mapped = Arr::map($array, function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->student_id == 3 ? $value: '';
});
```